# Клик по чекбоксу внутри div

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите, столкнулся со следующей проблемой, есть такая штука на HTML:

```js
$('.check_group').click(function () {
    var check = $(this).children('input')[0];
    check.checked = !check.checked;
    alert(check.checked);
    //Дальше собираюсь убирать/показывать все чекбоксы в соседних div
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check_group" style="background-color: rgb(200, 138, 59);">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  - Выбрать все
</div>
```

Так вот, при клике на checkbox - меняется состояние чекбокса, а потом срабатывает jQuery и состояние меняется обратно.

Как сделать так чтобы при клике по диву/чекбоксу - менялся чекбокс и появлялся алерт о том что что-то произошло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел временное решение проблемы:

```js
$('.check_group').click(function (e) {
    var check = $(this).children('input')[0];
    if (e.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
         check.checked = !check.checked;
    }
    check.checked = !check.checked;
    alert(check.checked);
    //Дальше собираюсь убирать/показывать все чекбоксы в соседних div
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check_group" style="background-color: rgb(200, 138, 59);">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  - Выбрать все
</div>
```

Но очень буду рад другим примерам без использования "target" (я знаю что в данном случае его можно сделать более "человеческим" но мне пока не подходит)

Answer (score 3):

Во первых - зачем именно так? Можно же добавить `label` и стилизовать нужным образом.
Во вторых - повесть обработчик на `check_group input[type=checkbox]` и отменять пересылку события выше по DOM-у. ЕМНИП, `prevendDefault`

Comment: Желательно чтобы изменение происходило именно по div. А с "prevendDefault" - не совсем понятно, очень был бы рад примеру)

Comment: `$('check_group input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });` - как-то так. Да и документацию не должно быть проблемно нагуглить :-)

Comment: Ни по клику, ни по mousedown-у не блокируется =( Я в вопросе код подправил - он теперь активный. Если будет свободная минута - можно рабочий пример?)